# how to zscore normalize pandas column with nans?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy

I have a pandas dataframe with a column of real values that I want to zscore normalize:

```
>> a
array([    nan,  0.0767,  0.4383,  0.7866,  0.8091,  0.1954,  0.6307,
        0.6599,  0.1065,  0.0508])
>> df = pandas.DataFrame({"a": a})
```

The problem is that a single `nan` value makes all the array `nan`:

```
>> from scipy.stats import zscore
>> zscore(df["a"])
array([ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan])
```

What's the correct way to apply `zscore` (or an equivalent function not from scipy) to a column of a pandas dataframe and have it ignore the `nan` values? I'd like it to be same dimension as original column with `np.nan` for values that can't be normalized

**edit**: maybe the best solution is to use `scipy.stats.nanmean` and `scipy.stats.nanstd`? I don't see why the degrees of freedom need to be changed for `std` for this purpose:

```
zscore = lambda x: (x - scipy.stats.nanmean(x)) / scipy.stats.nanstd(x)
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Well the `pandas'` versions of `mean` and `std` will hand the `Nan` so you could just compute that way (to get the same as scipy zscore I think you need to use ddof=0 on `std`):

```
df['zscore'] = (df.a - df.a.mean())/df.a.std(ddof=0)
print df

        a    zscore
0     NaN       NaN
1  0.0767 -1.148329
2  0.4383  0.071478
3  0.7866  1.246419
4  0.8091  1.322320
5  0.1954 -0.747912
6  0.6307  0.720512
7  0.6599  0.819014
8  0.1065 -1.047803
9  0.0508 -1.235699
```

Comment: If you want to get the z_score on all DataFrame, you can try to use this:
``` def z_score(df):
    return (df-df.mean())/df.std(ddof=0)```  and ```df.apply(z_score)```

Comment: Although I would consider using ddof=1 for statistical datasets for small samples

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure since when this parameter exists, because I have not been working with python for long. But you can simply use the parameter *nan_policy = 'omit'* and nans are ignored in the calculation:

```
a = np.array([np.nan,  0.0767,  0.4383,  0.7866,  0.8091,  0.1954,  0.6307, 0.6599, 0.1065,  0.0508])
ZScore_a = stats.zscore(a,nan_policy='omit')

print(ZScore_a)
[nan -1.14832945  0.07147776  1.24641928  1.3223199  -0.74791154
0.72051236  0.81901449 -1.0478033  -1.23569949]
```

Answer (score 6):

You could ignore nans using [`isnan`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html).

```
z = a                    # initialise array for zscores
z[~np.isnan(a)] = zscore(a[~np.isnan(a)])
pandas.DataFrame({'a':a,'Zscore':z})

     Zscore       a
0       NaN     NaN
1 -1.148329  0.0767
2  0.071478  0.4383
3  1.246419  0.7866
4  1.322320  0.8091
5 -0.747912  0.1954
6  0.720512  0.6307
7  0.819014  0.6599
8 -1.047803  0.1065
9 -1.235699  0.0508
```

Comment: I think you need "z = a.copy()" rather than "z = a", otherwise z is pointing to the same array and you'll overwrite the elements of a with their zscores.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative solution to this problem is to fill the NaNs in a DataFrame with the column means when calculating the z-score. This will result in the NaNs being calculated as having a z-score of 0, which can then be masked out using `notna` on the original df.

You can create a DataFrame of the same dimensions as the original df, containing the z-scores of the original df's values and NaNs in the same places in one line with:

```
zscore_df = pd.DataFrame(scipy.stats.zscore(df.fillna(df.mean())), index=df.index, columns=df.columns).where(df.notna())
```