# Applying zscore function for every row in selected columns of Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

With the following code:

```
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale

df = pd.DataFrame({"Probe":["1430378_at","1439896_at","1439896_at"],
                   "Gene":["2900011G08Rik","Trappc5","Limk2"],
                   "A.x1":[0.0767,  0.4383,  0.7866],
                   "A.x2":[0.8091,  0.1954,  0.6307],
                   "A.x3":[ 0.6599,  0.1065,  0.0508]
                  }
                  )
df = df[["Probe","Gene","A.x1","A.x2","A.x3"]]
```

I can get the following data frame:

```
In [55]: df
Out[55]:
        Probe           Gene    A.x1    A.x2    A.x3
0  1430378_at  2900011G08Rik  0.0767  0.8091  0.6599
1  1439896_at        Trappc5  0.4383  0.1954  0.1065
2  1439896_at          Limk2  0.7866  0.6307  0.0508
```

What I want to do is to compute `z-score` for column `Ax1,x2,x3`.
How can I achieve that?

For example for the second row we compute z-score with the following

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
scale([0.4383,0.1954,0.1065],axis=0,with_mean=True, with_std=True,copy=False)
Out[61]: array([ 1.36603199, -0.36604999, -0.999982  ])
```

finally we expect to get:

```
        Probe           Gene        A.x1    A.x2        A.x3
0  1430378_at  2900011G08Rik  -1.38769528  0.92991195  0.45778333
1  1439896_at        Trappc5  1.36603199  -0.36604999  -0.999982
2  1439896_at          Limk2  0.93889666  0.44644183  -1.3853385
```

Comment: This seems similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24761998/pandas-compute-z-score-for-all-columns/24762240#24762240

Answer (score 1):

With Pandas it's often a good idea to try and use `apply` together with an anonymous function to perform your calculation on every row. Does this work for you?:

```
    df.iloc[:,2:5] = df.filter(regex = 'A.x').apply(
            lambda V: scale(V,axis=0,with_mean=True, with_std=True,copy=False),axis=1)
```