# Compute Z score for one column in python dataframe

Tags: python

I have a dataframe with three columns: 
1 - EmployeeID;
2 - date;
3 - amount.

Employee ID can be listed multiple times due to different dates associated. 
I need to calculate a Z score for the 3rd column only - amount.

How do I do that? I only found codes to do Z score for all columns.

Thank you!

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24761998/pandas-compute-z-score-for-all-columns/24762240#24762240

Answer (score 1):

Create a new column of zscore

```
avg = df['amount'].mean()
std = df['amount'].std()
df['zscore'] = ((df['amount']-avg)/std)
```