# How to calculate the z-score of all rows from an excel file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am incredibly new to python. I have an excel file that python read using pandas. Each row of that file has a couple thousand numerical values. I want to calculate the z-score of each row and then plot the data. Can anyone help me with this, please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a good tool!

I believe Pandas is the best you can ask for. It has a [read_excel()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) function that will automatically read the file and put it in a DataFrame.

If Pandas does not work, you can do it yourself (more manual labor) using the built-in module [CSV](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Here is how it may look like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('path\to\your\file.xls')
mean = df['your-values'].mean()
...
```

EDIT:
[how to compute the z-score with Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24761998/pandas-compute-z-score-for-all-columns)

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your response. I did use Pandas. I used Pandas to read an excel file that is filled with numerical values. I want to calculate the z-score of each row in that file now, and I don't quite understand how to compute that using python!

Comment: I gave you a link on how to compute the z-score with pandas. It should have everything you need. But tell me if you need help.